# Flipping a function across $y = -x$

Tags: functions

Is there a general rule of flipping a function, for example $$f(x)=\frac{2x-3}{7x-5}$$ across the line $y = -x$ on the Cartesian plane? I’ve read some articles about it but it doesn’t very help because I’m ver poor at math. When you answer can you make it as simple as possible? Thanks!

Comment: Such a flip does not always preserve "functionhood": For example, $f(x) = x^2$ is clearly a function, but its reflection across $y = -x$ yields $x = -y^2$, with each negative value of $x$ corresponding to two values of $y$.  Is that a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply convert $(x,y)\rightarrow (-y,-x)$. In this case, whenever you see an $x$ term, change it to $-y$. Whenever you see a $y$ term, change it to $-x$. To get some intuition on why this is true, sketch a graph! A more formal proof follows from this.

Answer (score 0):

When you flip across the line $y=-x$, the $y$ coordinate of all points obviously becomes $-x$. By rearranging the equation, we can see that the $x$ coordinate becomes $-y$. This means you can just do that substitution to get the new graph. For example, your $y=\frac{2x-3}{7x-5}$ becomes $-x=\frac{-2y-3}{-7y-5}$. Then, you can of course always simplify the equation.

Comment: Just for clarity, I replaced your $f(x)$ with $y$. As @BrianTung said, that means your new equation is not always a valid function.